# ggplot2 - scales: How to specify negate behaviour in limits parameter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `limits` under the `scale_x_discrete` scale. Now I'm familiary with specifying which factors you want to take with through the `limits` parameter in a normal way: e.g `limit = c("x", "y")`

But if I have a long list of factors, and want to negate say `"x"`, I can't seem to find the right syntax (if this is even possible). I've tried  `scale_x_discrete(limits = -c("x"))` and other variations, but they have all generated errors. What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this within the `limits` argument, you could do it like this:

```
limits = setdiff(levels(your_data$your_x_variable), c("x", "other_level_to_omit"))
```

But I think the most natural way would be just to subset your data before plotting.

```
ggplot(your_data[your_data$your_x != "x", ], ...)
```

(or use `subset` or `dplyr::filter` or whatever idiom you prefer)